# Bootstrap 4: Fitting a Header & Footer + Google maps with 100% Height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a webppage using Boostrap 4.1 that contains a header, a Google map filling 100% of the content and a footer underneath the map.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             Header                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             Content                               |
|                              (map)                                |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
|                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             Footer                                |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently i am having alot of trouble fitting everything on the screen. It keeps adding a scrollbar because the footer falls off the page. Is there a way to fit the map on the screen so it fills the space between the header & footer?

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my current progress in a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/11n0n6u1/1/

Comment: You can set height with css of **#map-canvas**  `height: calc(100vh - 102px);` where 102px is the total height of header and footer including margin.

Comment: Azhar, that's not a very responsive solution. Say the header and footer change size, you'd have to re-calculate the size of the map every time. That's far from ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrapped the entire content in a `div`, that I've given the following classes: `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between fullHeight`.
The `fullHeight` class does one thing, it gives the div `height: 100vh;`.
What this all does is create a flex div and lets the map fill up all remaining space between the header and footer.

See here for my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/od5jrfau/

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code updated

`Updated link`https://jsfiddle.net/qgah75x2/

Shortly description:
You can set height for header and footer, and for map you can calculate like 100% - heightofheader - heightof footer.

Or you can set height of header of footer i.e. 5%/5vh and height of map 90%/90vh

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting an absolute height to anything, because this could cause overflow issues if anything changes, and you'd have to change the `height` every time something changes in the header or footer.

Comment: I am agree with you, for this problem is so many solutions, many different approach could be used.